# $\sum_{i=1} h^{2+2i} = O(h^4)?$

Tags: integration, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

To elaborate, we have $h_n$ with $h_n \to 0$ and $nh_n \to \infty$.

Then is it true that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty h_n^{2i+2} = O(h_n^4)?$.

Here is where my question comes from.

[image]

Basically, we are integrating $\int K(u)[f(x)-huf'(x) + \frac{h^2 u^2}{2} f''(x) - \frac{h^3 u^3}{3!} f'''(x) + \frac{h^4 u^4}{4!} f''''(x) + \ldots)$.

where $\int u^n K(u) = 0$ for any $n$ odd as $K$ is symmetric about $0$.

Since we get an order $O(h_n^4)$, seems like this would imply that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty C_i h_n^{2i+2} = O(h_n^4)?$ for some constant $C_i$s.

But I'm not sure. So help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

EDIT:

And how are we getting this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you extract common terms, you get
$$
h^4\sum_{i=0}^\infty C_{i+1}h^{2i}.
$$

Of course one needs that the series has a positive radius of convergence to make the claim that the expression is $O(h^4)$.